# Scraping WordPress reviews

Tags: html, r, wordpress

I am just learning R programming. For an exercise, I want to scrape reviews of a WordPress plugin that seems to have been discontinued [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/demo-data-creator/)

I start by specifying the URL

```
> url <- 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/demo-data-creator/#reviews'
```

Scraping the HTML content from the URL

```
> url <- read_html('https://wordpress.org/plugins/demo-data-creator/#reviews')
```

Extract the title of each review using the ID tag

```
> reviews <- html_nodes(url, 'h3.review-title')
```

Strip out the HTML tags, leaving only the content of the title

```
> titletext <- html_text(reviews)
```

Print the titles scraped

```
> head(titletext)

> [1] "Good for development"                                          
> [2] "Used it for creating test users"                               
> [3] "Excelent! negative comments come from people who doesn't read!"
> [4] "Thanks"                                                        
> [5] "Does EXACTLY what it says it will – thanks! Very Handy"        
> [6] "Dangerous plugin"
```

I repeat the same for the contents of the reviews

```
> reviewcontent <- html_nodes(url, 'div.review-content')
> reviewtext <- html_text(reviewcontent)
```

And prints out

```
> head(reviewcontent)

> {xml_nodeset (6)} [1] <div class="review-content">Good and handy tool
> for deve ... [2] <div class="review-content">This plugin came in very
> han ... [3] <div class="review-content">Does exactly what it offers!
> ... [4] <div class="review-content">Thanks</div> [5] <div
> class="review-content">Very handy for a test system ... [6] <div
> class="review-content">I have to agree with viesli  ...
```

However, I realized it didn't scrape all the reviews as there are more [here](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/demo-data-creator/reviews/)

Is there a way to tell R to check each review listed to extract the title and review content and probably populate in a table?

Comment: I didn't really understand what you're asking. Would you clarify? Are you trying to extract the reviews from the 2nd link (with all reviews)? Or are you trying to merge the two review lists (from 1st and 2nd links)/

Comment: Thanks, @Aziz. I am trying to extract reviews from the 2nd link as that is where all the reviews are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach to extract the reviews from the second link. The **main difference** is that **the content of each review is in its own page**. Hence, you need two steps:

1. Extract the **list of review page URLs** from the main page.
2. For **each** URL, **fetch** the page, and **extract** the title and content of the review.

For **step 1**, it is very similar to what you already did, except that you are now trying to extract the URLs for the review pages. If you inspect that page, you'll see that these links (`<a>` elements) have CSS class `bbp-topic-permalink`.

[image]

So, we can extract them using:

```
links <- html_nodes(page, css='a.bbp-topic-permalink')
```

Now, we don't want the *text* part of the tag, but rather the `href` attribute value (where the link is pointing). We can extract that using

```
reviewurls <- html_attr(links, 'href')
```

For **step 2**, we will loop over the list of `reviewurls`, and for each one, fetch the page using `read_html`, extract the title and the content using `html_node` and `html_text`, then add them to a table/matrix/data.frame.

The loop can be done using:

```
for (u in reviewurls) {

}
```

Inside the loop, `u` is the variable that holds the current review URL. We will use `read_html` to read the page, then extract the title and content.

Inspecting the review page, the title is in an `<h1>` tag with CSS class `page-title`. Simiarly, thThe content of the review are inside a `<div>` with CSS class `bbp-topic-content`.

[image]

So, inside the loop, you can do this:

```
 page = read_html(u)
 reviewT = html_text(html_node(page, css='h1.page-title'))
 reviewC = html_text(html_node(page, css='div.bbp-topic-content'))
```

Now you will have both the title and the content for that particular review. You can add them to a list, so that by the end of the loop, you will have titles and contents of all the reviews.

The final code will look like this:

```
url <- 'https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/demo-data-creator/reviews/'
page <- read_html(url)
links <- html_nodes(page, css='a.bbp-topic-permalink')
reviewurls <- html_attr(links, 'href')

# Two empty lists, to be populated inside the loop
titles = c()
contents = c()

for (u in reviewurls) {
  page = read_html(u)
  reviewT = html_text(html_node(page, css='h1.page-title'))
  reviewC = html_text(html_node(page, css='div.bbp-topic-content'))

  titles = c(titles, reviewT)
  contents = c(contents, reviewC)
}
```

Once it's done, you will get:

```
> length(titles)
[1] 21

> head(titles)
[1] "Good for development"                                          
[2] "Used it for creating test users"                               
[3] "Excelent! negative comments come from people who doesn't read!"
...

> head(contents)
[1] "\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tGood and handy tool for development.\n\n\n\n\t\tThis topic was modified 2 years, 10 months ago by Subrata Sarkar.\n\t\n\n"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[2] "\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tThis plugin came in very handy during development of my own plugin. I used it to create a lot of users and it did exactly what it should.\nNot sure where all the negativity about wiping the database comes from. Are they users that didn’t read all the warnings? Or did older versions of the plugin not warn about wiping all data? Anyway, now it does \U0001f642\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t"                                                            
[3] "\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tDoes exactly what it offers! Nothing less.\nPeople complaining is too lazy to read the SEVERAL warnings about the usage of this plugin.\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t" 
...
```

Comment: Hi @Aziz. The solution is simpler than I imagined! Is it possible to spin the loop around such that it searches more than a summary page? I mean, some of the plugins have lots of reviews spanning 5 to 10 pages like [link](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easyrecipe/reviews/).

Comment: @Maybellyne Yes, you need an outer loop for pages. So, first get the list of page URLs, then for each page, a list of review URLs, then for each review, the titles and content. You will have 2 nested loops in total.

Comment: The nested loop has me confused. I have the outer loop for other pages:
`for (p in firstPage) {
  firstPage <- 'https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easyrecipe/reviews/'
  firstPage <- read_html('https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easyrecipe/reviews/')
  firstPage <- html_nodes(firstPage, css=('a.bbp-topic-permalink')
  firstPage <- html_text('href') 
for (u in otherPages) {
 pageURLs <- read_html('https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/easyrecipe/reviews/')
 pageURLs <- html_nodes(pageURLs, css='a.pagenumbers')
 pageURLs <- html_attr('href')
   }
 titles = c()
 contents = c()
}`

Comment: Handling pages is a little more complicated. The first page does not link to all the review pages. It only shows a small subset of them (e.g. the first and last 3). A better approach is to use the "Next Page" link (`a.next.page-numbers`), which points to the next page. So, after processing a page, check if it has a "Next Page" link. If so, update the URL and loop again.